# Efficiently uploading files to a CDN

Tags: php, file-upload, cron, cdn

I'm using Rackspace's CDN for hosting all my website's media (images and video).  Every time a user uploads something, I use this process:

1. Uploadify sends the file upload to a PHP method
2. The PHP method hashes the file name, uploads the file to a `tmp` directory, creates a thumbnail version (if necessary), and returns both the hashed file name and the thumbnail name
3. jQuery is used to replace a preview image src's with: `/location/to/tmp/file_name` and store the file_name also in a hidden input.
4. When the form is submitted, the $_POST value for the hidden input is used to upload the file to the CDN, and store the CDN location in a relational MySQL table

This is all fine -- everything works.

But I've been wondering lately if this is the most efficient way of doing this -- because, at the moment, the script is uploading the file to the CDN in the middle of the method which processes the file.  Sometimes the form will have up to 10-12 images (some more than 1MB), so that's a lot of data transfer to do in the middle of a processing function -- I'm worried that it will unnecessarily slow things down.  It's alright on my localhost, and on a shared host for staging, and I'm sure it'll be no problem when we roll it out on the production VPS, but I still want to get things as right as possible.

Should I leave all the CDN uploads to a cronjob, or is the approach I'm using right now okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It most likely depends on limitations (if there are any) enforced on the Rackspace CDN - and how many concurrent users you have uploading.

If they have a limit and you might get close to reaching it on production environment - it would be safer to implement some sort of queuing server for CDN upload.